# How to create empty cells in pandas that are recognized as empty by R, using rpy2?

Tags: python, r, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am attempting to perform operations below, which work fine, except for the issue with R not recognizing empty cells as empty. This error appears when R complains that there are more than two factors; R thinks that cells marked as 'nan' are actually not empty.

```
# Set up the df
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2], 'col2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['valence_median_split'] = ''

#Get median of valence
valence_median = df['col1'].median()
df['valence_median_split'] = np.where(df['col2'] < valence_median, 'Low_Valence', 'High_Valence')
df['temp_selection'] = np.nan
low = df.loc[df['valence_median_split'] == 'Low_Valence', 'valence_median_split'].sample(n=2).index
high = df.loc[df['valence_median_split'] == 'High_Valence', 'valence_median_split'].sample(n=2).index
df['temp_selection'] = np.select([df.index.isin(low), df.index.isin(high)], ['Low', 'High'], default= np.nan)

# Push it to R and run a t-test
%Rpush df
%R colnames(df)
%R All_Valence_Mean_Res <- t.test(col2 ~ temp_selection, data = df, var.equal = TRUE)
```

Error:

```
Error in t.test.formula(col2 ~ temp_selection, data = df, var.equal = TRUE) : 
  grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels
```

Verifying in python that the df does indeed have more than 2 unique values:

```
df['temp_selection'].unique()
array(['Low', 'nan', 'High'], dtype=object)
```

I tried setting df['valence_median_split'] to '' as well as np.nan, and both seem to generate this problem in R.

Comment: I also tried setting defaults to "na" and using na.action=na.omit, but getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This is small enough, you can look at the whole df:

```
In [821]: df                                                                    
Out[821]: 
   col1  col2 valence_median_split temp_selection
0     1     1          Low_Valence            nan
1     2     2          Low_Valence            nan
2     3     3         High_Valence            nan
3     4     4         High_Valence            nan
4     3     3         High_Valence           High
5     3     3         High_Valence           High
6     2     2          Low_Valence            Low
7     2     2          Low_Valence            Low
```

In what sense is a `nan` value considered to be 'empty'?

Comment: I tried nan because r has several functions for classifying that value as blank (or missing- something to be ignored).